# Should I include a "temporary" job on my resume?

Tags: resume

I took a job as a program control analyst as I needed to get out of my last job as a Systems Engineer, because the company was a mess. I took the first job I could get and I've been a PCA for 4 months now. I can't seem to find another job in a STEM field.

Should I include the PCA job on my resume?

Comment: You should probably delete this question and ask a fresh one. There are also several similar questions on this site already, so you may want to check those!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to start:

- The verbs are good, but the lists should be parallel. Most of the resume uses -ed endings, except the first.
- Seek to quantify your achievements. How many projects have you budgeted for? What was the budget? How many work plans did you develop? How many users did you train? What was the modern web-based application? Did you code it, or did you plan it?
- Add more emphasis. The education is listed twice. Leadership strengths are self-evaluative and should probably be determined by the facts of your experience instead. (How many people did you lead? To achieve what goal that increased revenue or cut spending for the company?) Seeing that you have two year's experience (you can approximate as 2, not 1.9 -- how many months is 0.9 anyway?) the resume may be cut down to one page to emphasize the most important points only.
- The employer must see what's in it for him. Remove your wants from the resume. Emphasize what you can do.
- The phrasing at the beginning is both vague and negative. *Better aligns with my goals and interests* doesn't suggest what your goal or interest is, and also says that you may be on a job without being satisfied.
- Let the facts speak. Result-driven and self-starter are overused. You probably aren't the best person to judge yourself anyway, so let the facts speak for themselves. Give yourself the closest title you've held towards what you're aiming for, and give a short one-sentence summary of yourself to set the tone.
- It's difficult to judge from the sidebar what skills you know best. Perhaps pick the ones you excel at or want to work using.

Don't get discouraged if your resume doesn't get much attention. It realistically probably won't unless you apply to a tonne of places. It's easier to network personally with other people.

You mention not being able to get a career coach. There is one on YouTube I've been listening to who is very helpful, and gives tips for resumes and job search, most of which inspired my comments: [Andrew LaCivita](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP1UlYJH_QL4m5HVyikcxfQ).

Sorry if this post seems overwhelmingly negative: I just wanted to point out potential improvements that seem pertinent. You seem to have good experience overall.

Comment: Looks like this answer was posted before some *extensive* edits to the question - it looked like such a non-sequitur I honestly thought it was a bot spam post until I checked the edit history and realised it was responding to specifics that were edited out. Probably worth an edit to address that.

Comment: @LizWeir Yeah, not sure what to do. This answered the original question. Now no one can see the original. When my answer got posted, the question had changed so much I had to search in my history to convince myself it was the same page.